# Xamarin Forms scrolling in ListView with custom ViewCell is not working for UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

When using a custom ViewCell for a ListView, it is almost impossible to scroll in UWP. The list items gets focus shortly and the list is not scrolled. (It works fine on Android).

When using a TextCell or ImageCell for scrolling works fine, but only the Text attribute of the TextCell is shown in the ListView. The Detail attribute of the TextCell is never shown. (This also works fine for Android).

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 and latest Xamarin version.

Comment: What version of Forms are you using? This vaguely sounds like a known issue which was recently fixed and should be available in the [nightly](https://blog.xamarin.com/try-the-latest-in-xamarin-forms-with-nightly-builds/) feed.

Comment: I was actually not running the latest version of Xamarin Forms. After upgrading to version 2.3.3.193 everything works as expected. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great. I'll add an answer just for sake of clarity on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Per comments on the question, this was resolved by updating their version of Forms.